# One-to-one relationship in EF Core (The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship)

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api, entity-framework-core-2.2

I've been getting the following error message and I can't seem to grasp the reason why have I been getting it. Interestingly when adding migrations I didn't get any errors, but whenever I want to use the context I do get it.

> The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one
>   relationship between 'Block.JobBlock' and 'JobBlock.Block'. To
>   identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the
>   foreign key property. If these navigations should not be part of the
>   same relationship configure them without specifying the inverse.

A `Job` can have multiple `JobBlocks` (one-to-many); single `Block` can have only one `JobBlock` (one-to-one). So basically, a `JobBlock` is a reference table/entity used to reference `Job` and its `Blocks`. It is important to mention that a primary key in the `JobBlock` entity consists of two keys thus making it a compound primary key.

One might argue that a `Block` entity should already contain an `IdJob` property and that the `JobBlock` entity could be entirely dismissed, but there is some reasoning why it shouldn't be done this way so let's leave it as it is :)

**Models:**

```
public class Job : IEntity
{
    public Job()
    {
        JobBlocks = new HashSet<JobBlock>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public ICollection<JobBlock> JobBlocks { get; set; }
}

public class Block : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public JobBlock JobBlock { get; set; }
}


public class JobBlock : IEntity
{
    public Guid IdJob { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }

    public Guid IdBlock { get; set; }
    public Block Block { get; set; }
}
```

**EF Configurations:**

```
public class JobConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Job>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Job> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        builder.Property(p => p.Id) .IsRequired() .ValueGeneratedNever();

        builder.HasMany(e => e.JobBlocks)
            .WithOne(e => e.Job)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.IdJob);
    }
}

public class BlockConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Block>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Block> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        builder.Property(p => p.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedNever();

        builder.HasOne(e => e.JobBlock)
            .WithOne(e => e.Block)
            .HasForeignKey<JobBlock>(p => new { p.IdJob, p.IdBlock });
    }
}

public class JobBlockConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<JobBlock>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<JobBlock> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => new { p.IdJob, p.IdBlock });
        builder.Property(p => p.IdJob).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(p => p.IdBlock).IsRequired();

        builder.HasOne(e => e.Job)
            .WithMany(e => e.JobBlocks)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.IdJob);

        builder.HasOne(e => e.Block)
            .WithOne(e => e.JobBlock)
            .HasForeignKey<JobBlock>(p => new { p.IdJob, p.IdBlock });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem is in your `Block` and `JobBlock` configuration. According to your requirement these two configurations should be as follows:

```
public class BlockConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Block>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Block> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        builder.Property(p => p.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedNever();

        builder.HasOne(e => e.JobBlock)
            .WithOne(e => e.Block)
            .HasForeignKey<JobBlock>(p => p.IdBlock); // <--- Here it is
    }
}
public class JobBlockConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<JobBlock>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<JobBlock> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => new { p.IdJob, p.IdBlock });

        // Key property is always required. You don't need to specify it explicitly.

        // You don't need to need specify one-one-one configuration
        //  between `Job and Block` and between `Block and JobBlock` in
        //  two places. You need to specify
        //  it only one place. That's why I have removed these from here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, but you don't need to / should not configure *any*  (not only *one-to-one*) relationship in two places, so remove the other relationship configuration from  `JobBlockConfiguration` as well.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes! You are correct! I did not notice this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Unfortunately I still get the same result even though the configurations look exactly as in your answer. Error message is still the same.

Comment: @wegelagerer I have tested in my side with a test project and everything generated perfectly without any issue. Please check your code again. And please also add the `IEntity` base to the question.

Comment: @TanvirArjel `IEntity` is empty, it isn't relevant for this case. Strange, because the code is 1:1 copy of your, but still doesn't work. Thank you anyway, I'll look into it.

Comment: @wegelagerer Better directly copy my code and replace your `Block` and `JobBlock` configuration. I assume you did not make  changes for `Block` block configuration as I have done.

Comment: @TanvirArjel - Ok, it's a bit embarassing to admit, but I've been using the wrong DbContext (I have 2 which are almost the same) :) I'll accept your answer since you gave me valuable infos on how to improve the configurations